# Unexpected result when calculating a percentage - even when factoring in integer division rules

Tags: c, percentage, integer-overflow, integer-division

I am trying to express a battery voltage as a percentage. My battery level is a (global) uint16 in mV. I have a 16-bit CPU. Here is my code:

```
static uint8 convertBattery(void){
    uint16 const fullBattery = 3000; /* 3V = 3000mV */
    uint8 charge;
    charge = ((battery*100)/fullBattery);
    return charge;
}
```

As you can see, I have factored in the integer division rounding down by multiplying the numerator by 100 first.

With a `battery = 2756` my charge values calculates as `04` which is unexpected. I've spent ages on this rather trivial task and haven't made any progress. Could anyone suggest where the problem is?

Thanks.

Comment: `04`??? hmm...how do you print it?

Comment: also, how about battery value less than `30`? Please provide a ___[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)___

Comment: [It's working correctly](http://ideone.com/NYWLMr) so i think your print code is the culprit

Comment: Where do you get battery value from? Is it always properly initialized before use?

Comment: Getting really tired of people posting snippets without all variable declarations available...

Comment: Sorry, but have to vote to close. Reason: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is the type of `battery`? What is the default operands width: 16 bits, 32 bits?

Comment: @Wolf You're really answering that question? :-) It was a rhetorical question, anyway.....

Comment: @SouravGhosh Asking about processing of different battery values is not a rhetorical question, but a question that would help, if the **asker** would answer it.

Comment: @Wolf that is one of the many questions OP should answer, not you or me or anybody can. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh OP seems too busy (spending even more *ages on this*) now. I guess he/she is coming back in a few hours and will be shocked about the "unfriendly response" ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I will update the original post with the missing information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Diagnosis

The value you expect is, presumably, 91.

The problem appears to be that your compiler is using 16-bit `int` values.

<sup>You should identify the platform on which you're working and include information about unusual situations such as 16-bit `int` types.  It is reasonable for us to assume 32-bit or 64-bit systems by default — they are by far the most common environments for questions on SO.</sup>

You have `battery = 2756`. If that is multiplied by 100, it gives you 275600 in 32-bit precision, but in 16-bit precision, it gives 13546, which, when divided by 3000, yields 4, the observed answer.

Here's code compiled with a 64-bit compiler that simulates the 16-bit calculation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    short battery = 2756;
    short fullbattery = 3000;
    short r1 = battery * 100;
    printf("r1 = battery * 100 = %d\n", r1);
    short r2 = r1 / fullbattery;
    printf("r2 = (battery * 100) / fullbattery = %d\n", r2);
    int r3 = (battery * 100) / fullbattery;
    printf("r3 = (battery * 100) / fullbattery = %d\n", r3);
    return 0;
}
```

The output from it is:

```
r1 = battery * 100 = 13456
r2 = (battery * 100) / fullbattery = 4
r3 = (battery * 100) / fullbattery = 91
```

To get a 16-bit calculation, I had to force the intermediate results into 16-bit variables.  Yes, there are other more elaborate ways of writing the code, using `uint16_t` etc.  And yes, the overflow in the assignment to `r1` is strictly undefined behaviour, but my compiler (GCC 5.1.0 on Mac OS X 10.10.3) appears to be giving a sane interpretation to the undefined behaviour.  This serves to demonstrate the point.

#### Plausible fix

You should be able to work around it on your machine by using `long`:

```
static uint8 convertBattery(void){
    uint16 const fullBattery = 3000; /* 3V = 3000mV */
    uint8 charge = (battery * 100L) / fullBattery;
    return charge;
}
```

The `L` in `100L` makes it a `long` value, which must be at least 32-bits in a conforming C compiler, so the multiplication must give a `long` value, and the divisor will be converted to `long` before the division, and the result will be a `long` (and the value will be 91), and you can assign that to `charge` safely.

Alternatively, you could use one or more explicit `(long)` casts in the calculation if you think this is too subtle.

Comment: Great job in software archaeology.

Comment: Wonderful answer and your fix worked. I've updated the OP with the missing information. 

I had attempted to explicitly cast one of the variables but your suggestions is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

The intermediate result of battery*100 is too large for an uint16, so it overflows.

Comment: Most possibly true, unless `battery` is of higher dimension.

Comment: But wouldn't the type of the intermediate result be wider? Promotion and all that nonsense..

Comment: Oh not necessarily, plenty of other things could be wrong, like the input value (giving 104% perhaps?) or the printing.

Comment: `battery*100` is assigned to a temporary, which has default integer size, but if this is 16 or 32 bits is still unknown (=not answered by the asker).

Comment: The answer '4' is exactly what you get with 16-bit overflow though. 2756*100 = 13456 (modulo 2^16), and 13456/3000 = 4.

Comment: Your answer is on the right track, but you're missing a comment about the C compiler converting anything shorter than an `int` to `int` before doing the computation, and if `int` is 16-bit, then the computation is done in 16-bit.  Note that in my answer, I had to force the erroneous result by explicit stores to 16-bit variables.  That's because the `short` values were converted to `int` before the computation, and the computation was performed in `int`, and on a 64-bit machine, `int` is a 32-bit quantity (usually), so there wasn't any overflow.

Comment: Ok, to be more specific: the output is compiler dependent. In this case there is an overflow, resulting in the wrong value. If you want to multiply 2756 by 100 you'd better not rely on the compiler, but explicitly use at least 32-bit variables.